# Cannot invoke 'addMutableTrackWithMediaType' with an argument list of type '(mediaType: String, preferredTrackID: Int)'

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, avfoundation

Xcode is throwing this error when we try to use `AVMutableComposition`:

```
Cannot invoke 'addMutableTrackWithMediaType' with an argument list of type  '(mediaType: String, preferredTrackID: Int)'
```

Code:

```
    let mixComposition = AVMutableComposition()
    let videoTrack = mixComposition.addMutableTrackWithMediaType(mediaType: AVMediaTypeVideo, preferredTrackID: kCMPersistentTrackID_Invalid)
```

We have also tried:

```
    let mixComposition = AVMutableComposition()
    let videoTrack = mixComposition.addMutableTrackWithMediaType(mediaType: "AVMediaTypeVideo", preferredTrackID: kCMPersistentTrackID_Invalid)

    let mixComposition = AVMutableComposition()
    let videoTrack = mixComposition.addMutableTrackWithMediaType(AVMediaTypeVideo, preferredTrackID: kCMPersistentTrackID_Invalid)
```

None of these work, and Google yields nothing helpful. What's causing the error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This corrected the compilation error, though it uses a different value for `preferredTrackId`:

```
    var videoTrack = mixComposition.addMutableTrackWithMediaType(AVMediaTypeVideo, preferredTrackID: CMPersistentTrackID())
```